# Google Voice stopped transcribing messages after switching to a different carrier

Tags: google-voice

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. I recently changed cellular carrier from Verizon to Consumer Cellular and I kept my phone & my number, so it was "ported" over.

Prior to this change, I was using *Google Voice*, because it types *transcripts* of voice mails received in to emails.  I have a Google Voice number, but never used it to make calls.

Google Voice stopped transcribing messages on the day I changed carrier. The Voice mail *setting* on my phone is set to Google Voice, but I am retrieving voice mails through Consumer Cellular.

How do I fix this issue?